# How to group by a table display method in a report?

Tags: report, axapta

I have a table CustInvoiceJour. I use report to print some info by grouping some fields (Sales Price, SalesUnit in the report Query. Report prints sum(LineDisc), sum(LineAmount) values.

I want to modify report adding one more group by field - but that field is display method. Axapta 3.0 only supports physical fields to group by.

What is the fastest possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but Axapta 3.0 does not support grouping by a display method and nor do any other version of AX.

AX 2012 support adding a [computed field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx) to a [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb314551.aspx), which would save your day in that version.

In all other version you will have to have a real field, then compute the field on insert or update.
For the `CustInvoiceJour` table you only need to change the `insert` method, as the table is never updated.

Comment: thank's for fast answer. This solution seems really fast and i used it. But creating additional fields in the table seems not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

*Version 1*: You can use Map class (Types::Container, Types::Container)to group data manually and MapItertor to send them to report.

*Version 2*: You can insert your data to temporary table and use 'select ... groupby' from this table to send data to the report.